# presence_of_element_located() not working as intended

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I use python/selenium for web-scraping and automation through Chrome. Recently I've come across a problem where some pages or websites would load endlessly as a means to prevent bots from scraping them (It often starts to happen after first time). I had no idea how to counter this until I came across the function in question:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3)
        
element = wait.until(
      EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[.="Sign up"]'))
)
```

The way I understood this function is that it sat a timeout for the page (3 seconds in this example) and at the same time checking whether an element has been loaded into the page or not. If the element has been loaded or if the wait times out, the program stops waiting for the page to load and continues on with the next line of code, which is, in my case, a `print("timeout")` function.

Thing is, as I use the function as demonstrated above the program still waits for the page to load, as "timeout" only appears in the console after I manually stop the page loading from the browser.

I am sure the element is present in the page (and quite visible) as it continues to load endlessly, because once I press the X button and stop the page loading, "timeout" is printed and the element is interacted with successfully.

I also tried `EC.visibility_of_element_located`to the same effect.

What is going wrong and how do I achieve the functionality I need?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page to let us give you more effective answer, not just trying to guess it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't share a link to the page you are working on I can only guess.
So my guess is: you are using a wrong locator.
Try using this

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3)
        
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(.,"Sign up")]')))
```

Or this

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3)
        
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(.,"sign up")]')))
```

Comment: "I am sure the element is present in the page (and quite visible) as it continues to load endlessly, because once I press the X button and stop the page loading, "timeout" is printed and the element is interacted with successfully."

Comment: I saw that. have you tried my suggestions? can you share a link to that page?

Comment: It's not a single page, it didn't work on https://temp-mail.org/en/ and https://watpad.com
Your suggestion is the exact same code just in a different format.

After a little bit of research I've come to understand that selenium's timeout functionality is unreliable and people are suggesting using threading instead.

Comment: Because there are no such elements there! At least not on `https://temp-mail.org/en/` page. `https://watpad.com/` not opened at all.

Comment: You can not assume you will have an element matching some specific locator on every and each web site!

Comment: The element in the post is just an example.

Comment: On https://temp-mail.org/en/ the element I'm looking for is an input with id=mail, using selenium's By.ID.

Comment: The point I mentioned of the element being successfully interacted with as planned upon my stopping the loading manually still stands.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what do you mean.

Comment: What part did you not understand?

Comment: The last. And I generally don't understand what are you asking in this question, if so.

Comment: I'm saying once I stop the loading of the page manually the value of the #mail input in the page is successfully read, therefore there is nothing wrong with the xpath, which is what you were suggesting I modify.

Comment: OK, so? I still don't understand what are you asking about here?

Comment: My initial question was why does the function in the post not work as intended, which to to go to next line of code upon finding the element I pass to it or upon timing out.